# How to synchronize database with an EF model by overriding the Seed method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm new to EF Code First approach and got a question.
I've created a sample SQL database using the mentioned approach. It works as expected.
My problem is how to update my tables as the model changes?
I've read and surf the web for that and finally the following solutions figured out:
1. DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
2. DropCreateDatabaseAlways
3. CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
4. Using Enable-Migrations in PM console that unfortunately coped with lots of syntax errors!
I know I need to override the Seed method which could be inherited from DropCreateDatabaseAlways. And I know I have to create objects in this method and add them to the context. BUT... what if my Customer table includes 100 records? 
Do I have to fetch them and add them to the context using a loop? I don't know but it seems not reasonable to me!

I appreciate any one could give a good solution. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I personally think the easiest method is to use Migrations. I use the method mentioned here, under the heading "Your First Automatic Migration":

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/02/15/using-entity-framework-4-3-database-migration-for-any-project.aspx

(I use EF 5.0 even if the article says 4.3, there is noe difference)

Comment: +1 Migrations are the way to go, but they're sometimes tricky to handle and to understand.